# C# App.xaml and Resource Dictionaries

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get my application (WPF) use a referenced assembly in my App.xaml using Pack URIs. In my solution I have several projects. In the base application, I just have my App.xaml. I would like this to use a referenced assembly.

Call my base project with App.xaml Project 1 (in the solution). This is the relevant part of App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyProject.Project2;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Project 2 has a folder "Themes" with Generic.xaml. I'm fairly sure that I'm doing the Pack URI incorrectly because none of the styling in Generic.xaml is being used (I'm overriding the default window with a custom window, but it does not currently work. Application shows up with default window styling, everything inside the window is black).

Folder hierarchy:

```
MainFolder
    Project 1
        App.xaml
        bin
            Debug
                Application.exe
    Project 2
        Themes
            Generic.xaml
```

Questions:

1. Can someone explain the `pack://application:,,,` syntax? What does all of this mean?
2. What am I doing wrong with the Pack URI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow this from MSDN Pack URI's in WPF - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Comment: @RV1987 I've done so, this code here is pulled more or less directly from that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out in MyProject.Project2 I needed the following code in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
//(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
// or application resource dictionaries)
ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
//(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
// app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first item in a Pack Uri after the ,,, is the name of the assembly. Make sure you set that:

`"pack://application:,,,/[ASSEMBLY name here];component/Themes/Generic.xaml"`

Comment: Yep, the assembly name is set properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the resource dictionary into project 2 instead of in App.xaml.